# Code below for Tabulator filter does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

I am using jquery pluggin called Tabulator and  trying to put a simple text box below all column headers in order to filter data. Seems like it can be done easily looking at the documentation but this just doesn't work for me
Link : http://tabulator.info/examples/4.5?#filter-header

There is no error but I simply do not see the text box where I can start inputting text to filter

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<div id="example-table"></div>




<script>
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Billy Bob", age:12, gender:"male", height:95, col:"red", dob:"14/05/2010"},
    {id:2, name:"Jenny Jane", age:42, gender:"female", height:142, col:"blue", dob:"30/07/1954"},
    {id:3, name:"Steve McAlistaire", age:35, gender:"male", height:176, col:"green", dob:"04/11/1982"},
];

//define table
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:tabledata,
    autoColumns:true,
    layout:"fitColumns",
    pagination:"local", //enable local pagination.
    paginationSize:2, // this option can take any positive integer value (default = 10)
    columns:[
    {title:"id", field:"id", headerFilter:"input"}, //never hide this column
    {title:"name", field:"name",headerFilter:"input"},
    {title:"age", field:"age",headerFilter:"input"}, //hide this column first
    {title:"gender", field:"gender",headerFilter:"input"},
    {title:"height", field:"height",headerFilter:"input"},
    {title:"col", field:"col",headerFilter:"input"},
    {title:"dob", field:"dob",headerFilter:"input"},
    ],
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a different source

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>




<div id="example-table"></div>



<script>


var minMaxFilterEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){

    var end;

    var container = document.createElement("span");

    //create and style inputs
    var start = document.createElement("input");
    start.setAttribute("type", "number");
    start.setAttribute("placeholder", "Min");
    start.setAttribute("min", 0);
    start.setAttribute("max", 100);
    start.style.padding = "4px";
    start.style.width = "50%";
    start.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

    start.value = cell.getValue();

    function buildValues(){
        success({
            start:start.value,
            end:end.value,
        });
    }

    function keypress(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            buildValues();
        }

        if(e.keyCode == 27){
            cancel();
        }
    }

    end = start.cloneNode();
    end.setAttribute("placeholder", "Max");

    start.addEventListener("change", buildValues);
    start.addEventListener("blur", buildValues);
    start.addEventListener("keydown", keypress);

    end.addEventListener("change", buildValues);
    end.addEventListener("blur", buildValues);
    end.addEventListener("keydown", keypress);


    container.appendChild(start);
    container.appendChild(end);

    return container;
 }

//custom max min filter function
function minMaxFilterFunction(headerValue, rowValue, rowData, filterParams){
    //headerValue - the value of the header filter element
    //rowValue - the value of the column in this row
    //rowData - the data for the row being filtered
    //filterParams - params object passed to the headerFilterFuncParams property

        if(rowValue){
            if(headerValue.start != ""){
                if(headerValue.end != ""){
                    return rowValue >= headerValue.start && rowValue <= headerValue.end;
                }else{
                    return rowValue >= headerValue.start;
                }
            }else{
                if(headerValue.end != ""){
                    return rowValue <= headerValue.end;
                }
            }
        }

    return false; //must return a boolean, true if it passes the filter.
}


var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150, headerFilter:"input"},
        {title:"Progress", field:"progress", width:150, formatter:"progress", sorter:"number", headerFilter:minMaxFilterEditor, headerFilterFunc:minMaxFilterFunction},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender", editor:"select", editorParams:{values:{"male":"Male", "female":"Female"}}, headerFilter:true, headerFilterParams:{values:{"male":"Male", "female":"Female", "":""}}},
        {title:"Rating", field:"rating", editor:"star", align:"center", width:100, headerFilter:"number", headerFilterPlaceholder:"at least...", headerFilterFunc:">="},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col", editor:"input", headerFilter:"select", headerFilterParams:{values:true}},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", align:"center", sorter:"date",  headerFilter:"input"},
        {title:"Driver", field:"car", align:"center", formatter:"tickCross",  headerFilter:"tickCross",  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true},headerFilterEmptyCheck:function(value){return value === null}},
    ],
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code snippet does not show any row/table. Just the colum headers. I noticed no codepen example works neither